# How-To: Getting Bootstrap-Notify working in my Angular page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**The Hope:**
I would like to use the Bootstrap Notify addon on my Angular page!

**BootStrap Notify**: [here](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/), and the [github location](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify)

**The Problem:**
I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it working! I've tried about 12 (ok, maybe 6) ways of injecting the script, but not a one of them results in anything except errors!

**The Code:**

*index.aspx:*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="tc" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    My awesome page!
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="pc" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <div id="ng-app" ng-app="myAwesomePage" ng-view growl autoscroll></div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="as" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-addons/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-addons/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-addons/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ng-v4/ng-v4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myAwesomePage/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myAwesomePage/controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myAwesomePage/services.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ac" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav, .pagination, .carousel a {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .pagination {
            margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
            font-family: Helvetica, FontAwesome;
        }

        [ng-cloak] {
            display: none;
        }

        label, form {
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

*app.js*

```
"use strict";

angular.module("myAwesomePage", [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngResource",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "v4",
    "bootstrapNotify",
    "myAwesomePage.controllers",
    "myAwesomePage.services"]).

    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        //Main List
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/content/myAwesomePage/index.html",
            controller: "myAwesomePageCtrl",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
    });
```

The problem I'm running into is with this line:

`"bootstrapNotify",`

I can't figure out how to inject the directive, and every version of the name that I've tried results in this error:

[image]

which leads to this awesome and intimately descriptive page on the [AngularJS website](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=DistributionList&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dnotify%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.7%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dnotify%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A252)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A495%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A427%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520h%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A444%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:38:184%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:37:444%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:41:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js:19:463).

I've tried `"bootstrap-notify"`, `"bootstrapnotify"`, `"bootstrapNotify"`, `"notify"`, `"Notify"`: all of them have failed and given the same error.

Help me, StackOverflow! You're my only hope!

Comment: you would get a better error (and a more descriptive page from the angular website) if you use angular.js instead of angular.min.js.

Comment: is `bootstrapNotify` an angular plugin? I can't find any reference suggesting that there is an angular version of this addon.  It's definitely not one of the directives included in ui-bootstrap.

Comment: @Claies - Absolutely, but I tend to not use anything other than minified includes - I don't like swapping out files over and over. :)

Comment: There are a whole bunch of things not in UI-Bootstrap that are angular plugins, but you might have something on this one being JQuery only. I'll look into it.

Comment: And I'll add a link to it, since I forgot that.

Comment: So, going with non-minified versions, I get this error:


`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bootstrapNotify due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'bootstrapNotify' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: right, because `bootstrapNotify` isn't an angular module.  from what I can find, it's never had an angular module written for it, at least in the more popular module kits, and definitely not in ui-bootstrap.  Unless you need to change angular values from the notify area, you don't need to inject it into angular, and angular doesn't really need to know that it exists;  it already exists on the page just by including it's script.

Comment: Alrighty. Well, that likely answers it. I'll look for an Angular version of this and hope I find one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per @Claies answer above, it turns out that BootstrapNotify isn't an angular module, and thus would require a massive amount of effort to actually get working with an angular page. Turns out it's more of something for JQuery-driven pages.